# Check if EC2 instances exists and running then skip deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am trying to run a playbook that calls a role to deploy some EC2 instances, everything works fine except that I want to put a condition when the EC2 instance exists and in running state to skip the deployment I used the following to retrieve the ec2_infos :

```yaml
## Check if an instance with same name exist on AWS
- name: Get {{ ec2_name }} infos
  ec2_instance_info:
    region: "us-east-1"
    filters:
      "tag:Name": "{{ ec2_name }}"
      instance-state-name: [ "running"]
  register: ec2_infos

- name: DEBUG
  debug: msg="{{ aws_ec2_infos }}"
```

and on the Deployment stage my condition is as follows :

```yaml
- name: "{{ ec2_description }} - {{ ec2_name }}"
  cloudformation:
    stack_name: "some name "
    state: "present"
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    template: "PATH/ec2.json"
    template_parameters:
      Name: "{{ ec2_name }}"
      Description: "{{ ec2_description }}"
      KeyName: "{{key_name }}"
      KmsKeyId: "{{ key_id }}"
      GroupSet: "{{ id }}"
      IamInstanceProfile: "{{ name }}"
      Type: "OS"
  **when: ec2_infos.state[0].name != 'running'**
```

but I get an error that says :

```sh
"msg": "The conditional check 'aws_ec2_infos.state[0].name != 'running'' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (aws_ec2_infos.state[0].name != 'running'): 'dict object' has no attribute
```

I think I am missing something in my condition but I can't find what exactly. Any tip or advice is more than welcome

Comment: It is exactly as the error message says, and the returned shape would be visible in your `name: DEBUG` step output, in case [reading the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/community/aws/ec2_instance_info_module.html#return-values) was more trouble that posting here

Comment: So, just from reading the manual pointed by @mdaniel: `when: aws_ec2_infos.instances[0] is not defined or aws_ec2_infos.instances[0].state.name != 'running'`. But you should get used to read the JSON or YAML output of `debug` and find your own way from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @benoit and @mdaniel said the error was in my understanding the condition should be :

```yaml
aws_ec2_infos.instances[0].state.name != 'running'
```